# Function return value in C

Tags: c, function, return

I am an absolute newbie to the C language (I started today to learn it). As a test I wrote this program to output all prime numbers between two ranges. I then optimized and shortened the `checkIfPrime` function with some google help and took all `return` statements out of the function, for it obviously doesn't need to have a return value to understand **I want to have the `flag` variable** back. How does the function returns the `flag` variable even without any `return`s in it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int checkIfPrime(int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n1, n2;

    scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);
    for (int i = n1; i < n2; i++) {
        if (checkIfPrime(i)) {
            printf("%s", "Is prime: ");
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int checkIfPrime(int n) {
    int flag = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= (n / 2); i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _for it obviously doesn't need to have a return value_ How did you conclude this? I guess you could use a global variable or a pointer, but I don't see how those are better than a `return`.

Comment: why don't you want to use `return` statements? They are the most efficient way to return a value to the caller.

Comment: google etc. is a really bad source to learn any programming language. For C there still are those paper-thingies (iirc, they are called "books") or their digital variant best to learn the language. You apparently have some massive missconceptions. And pay heed to compiler warnings! Enable them and treat the as errors you have to resolve **before** asking around.

Comment: @Olaf Yes i know, i have bought the book by Dennis Ritchie, but i haven't got it yet!

Comment: My question is why does the function work the same way without the `return flag;` at its end? I am already used to write returns every where i can from Python, but here it **seems** the function understands in some way to return the flag automatically.

Comment: @amirteymuri See my comment on the answer. UB is UB. That you got something recognisable and useful in this case, with this compiler, under this alignment of the planets, is entirely coincidental. Tomorrow and/or on another compiler or with a different wind direction, a program invoking UB could swap your front and back door while you're not looking. I mean, it's very unlikely, but again, anything's possible. Btw, which edition of K&R did you buy? If it's the pre-Standardisation one, better send it back for a swap.

Comment: Not sure which book you mean. But if you mean K&R-C, you should learn get a second one covering modern C. The book by **Kernighan** (and Ritchie) teaches mideval C in the second edition and ancient C in the first only. Never ever use the latter unless you have to maintain some historic code!

Comment: @Olaf + underscore_d I have bought the second edition: https://www.amazon.de/dp/0131103628/ref=pe_386171_145739541_TE_item_image

Comment: @amirteymuri great choice :)

Answer (score 6):

Unlike some languages such as Groovy where the last expression evaluated by a function is the return value of the function, in C you need to explicitly state the return value with a `return` statement.

```
int checkIfPrime(int n)
{
  int flag = 1;

  for (int i = 2; i <= (n / 2); i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      flag = 0;
      break;
    }
  }
  return flag;
}
```

If you fail to explicitly return a value from a function that expects one, your code invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

As an example of undefined behavior, your original code give the "correct" answer for me, but if I change the function to this:

```
int checkIfPrime(int n) {
    int flag = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= (n / 2); i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    // this loop should have no effect
    for (int i = 2; i <= (n / 2); i++) {
    }
}
```

In a properly behaving program, the extra loop added should have no effect.  But without a `return`, I get back this if I input `2` and `10`:

```
Is prime: 2
Is prime: 3
Is prime: 4
Is prime: 5
Is prime: 6
Is prime: 7
Is prime: 8
Is prime: 9
```

If you had put the `return` statement in place at the end of the function, things like this wouldn't happen.

Why the above code behaves the way it does is an implementation detail of the compiler in use.  A different compiler may have different output, or the same compiler with different optimization settings could have different output.

Comment: In many cases, the compiler will yell at you if you don't have a `return` statement in a non-void function.

Comment: @dbush My original version was exactly the same as yours, i just wanted to know why the function still works correctly without `return flag;`.

Comment: And that is an example of undefined behavior - if you don't have `return flag;` compiler is allowed to do anything. Including adding `return flag;`. It could have been something else.

Comment: @amirteymuri That's part of undefined behavior.  Your program may crash, it may give unexpected output, or it may appear to work.  In the latter case, a seemingly unrelated change to your program could cause it to stop working.  Add two additional variables to `checkIfPrime`, one before and one after, and see what that does.

Comment: @amirteymuri Learn early, and learn well: **undefined behaviour** means just that. It means the C Standard does not define what must happen. So compilers can pretend the undefined thing and anything that relies on it never happened, or just do whatever random thing is fastest. Anything can happen. Or nothing. Or worse. You cannot rely on it, and things that _happen to_ happen are not worth discussing. But in this case maybe the result you wanted happened to be stored in a register, and without you supplying a defined value to return, that's what it got. It's incidental and wholly uninteresting

Answer (score 3):

Your current function int checkIfPrime(int n) is by its definition saying it will return an int, so you must then return an int value.

If you *really* didn't want to return a value using the return statement, you could pass the value back as a pointer to a variable to store the flag in:

```
void checkIfPrime(int n, int *flag) {
  *flag = 1;

  for (int i = 2; i <= (n / 2); i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
        *flag = 0;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Its far easier to read and understand using a return of the value though, and main would then have to change to allocate a new variable and would have to call the function and then check the variable - much nicer just using the return value.

Answer (score 2):

There are only two ways to give a value back from a function: explicitly return a value, or mutate a variable external to the function.

Except when writing OO code (and in that case you're mutating object fields), or a `void` function, your functions should always explicitly return a value.

Since you gave your function a return type, I'm surprised the compiler didn't raise an error.

You shouldn't try to avoid using return statements; avoid using them in ways that lead to confusing code.

Comment: Well, there's also the option of passing a pointer and updating the value pointed at…

Comment: @JonathanLeffler When I write to this answer, I was considering that mutating a global variable, but because of how I worded it, it's wrong. I'll try to correct the wording.

Answer (score 1):

> How does the function returns the flag variable even without any returns in it?

It doesn't; or, it doesn't do so in a predictable or reliable manner.

The *intent* is that if you define a function `T f() { ... }` and `T` is not `void`, then you will have at least one `return` statement returning a value of type `T`.

For whatever reason, the language definition does not mandate a `return` statement in a non-`void` function<sup>1</sup> (the compiler *may* complain, but it's not *required* to), but if the caller attempts to use the return value of the function and you don't explicitly return a value, then the behavior is undefined, meaning any result you get (whether expected or not) is considered "correct".

---

1. Interestingly, it *does* mandate that a `return` statement in a `void` function not return a value.

Comment: Any ideas what possible use-cases exist for being able to return an uninitialized value & only being UB if the caller uses it, i.e. why was this ever allowed? Was it to ease compilers' static analysis, or is there some pattern that grants it tenuous legitimacy? I suppose if the function can be called in such a way that the return value is irrelevant - perhaps signalled by particular input arguments - then the problem is circumvented by the caller acting as if the function returns `void`. But again, such a 'two-faced' function would be a tremendous code smell... & I'll stop thinking aloud now!

Comment: "The _intent_ is" surely rather that _all reachable code paths_ must return a `T`, not just "at least one". Also, re the footnote, isn't that just because a `void`-returning function physically doesn't have any space allocated into which to put any `return`ed value? That's quite different. If it somehow _did_ allow `return`ing a value of unexpected and arbitrary size, then who knows what would get clobbered by it.

Comment: The reason for allowing return with no value in a function that returns a value is historical.  Before the standard, there was no `void`.  Functions returned `int` by default, but you could write `return;` in such a function as long as the calling code didn't try to use the value.  This is no longer important, but it was crucial in 1989 and the next few years.  Invalidating huge quantities of existing code would have made the standard fail.